# Is this argument valid? If $p$ is a prime and $p \neq 2,3,$ show that $\bar{p} = \bar{1}$ or $\bar{p} = \bar{5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6.$

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

> If $p$ is a prime and $p \neq 2,3,$ show that $\bar{p} = \bar{1}$ or $\bar{p} = \bar{5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6.$

First, I showed that $\bar{p} \neq \bar{0},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4}.$

**(1)** $\bar{p} \neq \bar{0},$ because $6|p - 0 \implies 6|p \implies$ $p$ is not prime.

**(2)** $\bar{p} \neq \bar{2},$ because $6|p - 2$ implies that $6$ divides some odd number $x$ (all primes $p > 2$ are necessarily odd, and so $p - 2$ is odd), which in turn implies that $2$ divides $x,$ which contradicts that $x$ is odd.

**(3)** $\bar{p} \neq \bar{3},$ because $6|p - 3$ implies that $6d = p - 3$ for some integer $d,$ and $6d + 3 = 3(2d + 1) = p,$ which contradicts that $p$ is prime.

**(4)** $\bar{p} \neq \bar{4}$ for the same reason $\bar{p} \neq \bar{2}.$

Now, I simply show that $\bar{p} = \bar{1}$ and $\bar{p} = \bar{5}$ are each possible. I give the examples:

**(1)** $p = 7 \implies \bar{p} = \bar{1}$

**(2)** $p = 11 \implies \bar{p} = \bar{5}.$

Comment: You didn't say what $\bar x$ means -presumably the remainder modulo $6$?

Comment: Hi. Yes please excuse me! I forgot to include that

Comment: That I must also show that those two cases ARE valid. Not simply that they have to be one or the other. Or is it still logically redundant?

Comment: Based on the question you asked, it is unnecessary to show that there are actually any primes of the claimed form. You just need to rule out the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, but you can dispense with providing examples for $\bar1$ and $\bar5$. Since $\bar p$ can only be one of $\bar0$ to $\bar5$ – a complete residue system – by eliminating four of those cases you have shown that it must be one of the remaining two.

Comment: Hi. I suppose I interpreted the question differently?

Comment: That I must also show that both those cases occur. Not simply that has to be one or the other. Or is it still logically redundant?

Comment: Thanks for your response parcly!